# Geometric sequence problem with the last term (2018) undetermined.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $x_0 = 1$
>   $x_{n+1}=2x_{n}+1$
>   $S_n=x_0+x_1+\ldots+x_n$
>   $\text {Find } S_{2018}$

How can I solve it?
I tried to understand the sum of sequence but I couldn't and this is what I got:
$$1+3+7+15+31+\ldots$$

I really don't know how to calculate the $2018^{\text {th}}$ term. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use that $$x_n=2^{n+1}-1$$

Comment: @wolly You can write a program to calculate the sum.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Where did 2^(n+1)-1 come from?Did it came from the geometric sum formula?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Write the sequence $x_0+1$, $x_1+1$, $x_2+1$, $x_3+1$, ...